# what is the different between ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

```
var faraWorkspaceApp = angular.module("FaraWorkspace", ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);
```

what is the different between `ngRoute` and `ui.router` in angularjs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine. Unlike the $route service in the Angular ngRoute module, which is organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

States are bound to named, nested and parallel views, allowing you to powerfully manage your application's interface.

From: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router